# ASP.NET MVC Edit ViewModel with DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble retrieving the correct value to my DropDownList Control within the Edit Action.

**Customer Model:**

```
    public class Customer
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    public string CustDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string CustFirstName { get; set; }
    public string CustLastName { get; set; }
    public string CustCompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CustAddress { get; set; }
    public string CustPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string CustMobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string CustEmailAddress { get; set; }

    public int StId { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
}
```

**State Model:**

```
    public class State
{
    public int StId { get; set; }
    public string StAbbr { get; set; }

    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

**Manufacturer Model:**

```
    public class Manufacturer
{
    public int MfrId { get; set; }
    public string MfrCompanyName { get; set; }
    public string MfrWebsiteDomainName { get; set; }
}
```

**CustomerFormViewModel**

```
public class CustomerFormViewModel
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Display Name is required!")]
    [Display(Name = "Display Name")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CustDisplayName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CustFirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CustLastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CustCompanyName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [StringLength(12)]
    [RegularExpression(@"((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone Number format!")]
    public string CustPhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Mobile Number")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [StringLength(12)]
    [RegularExpression(@"((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid  Number!")]
    public string CustMobileNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [StringLength(320)]
    public string CustEmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required!")]
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CustAddress { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required!")]
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public int StId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<State> States { get; set; }
}
```

**CustomerController:**

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private WebAppDbContext _context;

    public CustomerController(WebAppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: /<Customer>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_context.Customers.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var states = _context.States.ToList();
        var viewModel = new CustomerFormViewModel
        {
            States = states
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CustomerFormViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var customer = new Customer();
            {
                customer.CustDisplayName = vm.CustDisplayName;
                customer.CustFirstName = vm.CustFirstName;
                customer.CustLastName = vm.CustLastName;
                customer.CustCompanyName = vm.CustCompanyName;
                customer.CustAddress = vm.CustAddress;
                customer.CustPhoneNumber = vm.CustPhoneNumber;
                customer.CustMobileNumber = vm.CustMobileNumber;
                customer.CustEmailAddress = vm.CustEmailAddress;
                customer.StId = vm.StId;
            }
            _context.Customers.Add(customer);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        else
        {
            vm.States = _context.States.ToList();
            return View(vm);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var customervm = new CustomerFormViewModel();
        {
            Customer customer = _context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustId == id);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            customervm.CustId = customer.CustId;
            customervm.CustDisplayName = customer.CustDisplayName;
            customervm.CustFirstName = customer.CustFirstName;
            customervm.CustLastName = customer.CustLastName;
            customervm.CustCompanyName = customer.CustCompanyName;
            customervm.CustAddress = customer.CustAddress;
            customervm.CustPhoneNumber = customer.CustPhoneNumber;
            customervm.CustMobileNumber = customer.CustMobileNumber;
            customervm.CustEmailAddress = customer.CustEmailAddress;
            customervm.StId = customer.StId;
        }
        return View(customervm);
    }
}
```

**Create View:**

```
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustDisplayName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustDisplayName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CustDisplayName)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustFirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustFirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustLastName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustLastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustCompanyName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustCompanyName, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustAddress)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustAddress, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CustAddress)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustPhoneNumber)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustPhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CustPhoneNumber)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustMobileNumber)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustMobileNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CustMobileNumber)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustEmailAddress)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustEmailAddress, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CustEmailAddress)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(s => s.StId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.StId, new SelectList(Model.States, "StId", "StAbbr"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.StId)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**Edit View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustDisplayName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustDisplayName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CustDisplayName)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustFirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustFirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustLastName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustLastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustCompanyName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustCompanyName, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustAddress)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustAddress, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CustAddress)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustPhoneNumber)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustPhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CustPhoneNumber)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustMobileNumber)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustMobileNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CustMobileNumber)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.CustEmailAddress)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CustEmailAddress, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CustEmailAddress)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(s => s.StId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.StId, new SelectList(Model.States, "StId", "StAbbr"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.StId)
</div>

@Html.HiddenFor(c => c.CustId)

<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is same as your create action, Load the collection property for all states (`States`) and also set the property for the selected item (StId) on your view model object.

So add this code to your Edit GET action method.

```
var customervm = new CustomerFormViewModel();
{
   // Your existing code to map the entity property values goes here
} 

//Load all the states

var states = _context.States.ToList();
customervm.States = states;

//Set the selected state
customervm.StId = customer.StId;

return View();
```

Comment: Now, can I reuse the same `var customervm = new CustomerFormViewModel();` for my Edit Post Action to actually save the updates or do I need to create another new CustomerFormViewModel on the Edit Post Action?

Comment: Depends on how similar your create and edit views are . Usually you can use the same. In create your Id will be null (make it nullable) and when submitted from Edit, it will have a valid value. based on this value, you determine whether to create a new record or update existing. You can use the same HttpPost action method for both's save(create and edit)